# Unable to make an API call from Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I am having a Rails Application `App2` listening on port 4000 and another Rails application `App1` listening on port 3000. `App2` has custom API calls defined which can be made use, only by an authenticated user.

A rake task is ran on `App1` which uses **HTTParty** to make API request as:

```
response = HTTParty.post("http://localhost:4000/users/sign_in",
    :basic_auth => {:user => {:email => "<User email>", :password => "<Password>"}},
    :headers => { 'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; ru; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; ru) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148a Safari/6533.18.5',
      'ContentType' => 'application/json' })
```

The output of `response.body`  shows that the user is not authenticated!

On analyzing the error, the development log shows:

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

Please help me on how to send CSRF token with the POST request from Rake task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in the POST request using `HTTParty`. The `basic_auth` should have been `body`. So the correct statement is:

```
response = HTTParty.post("http://localhost:4000/users/sign_in",
    :body => {:user => {:email => "<User email>", :password => "<Password>"}},
    :headers => { 'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; ru; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; ru) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148a Safari/6533.18.5',
    'ContentType' => 'application/json' })
```

CSRF token warning does not cause an issue! I got a response that I am authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

the CSRF token is used for security of your website users. it is injected into each form, valid just for a user session and the browser will have to send it over with each post to verify that the session was not hijacked.

if you have a dedicated api that does not need this security mechanism, you can just disable CSRF token validation in your application by skipping the `protect_from_forgery` check.

Comment: is there any way by which I can skip the `protect_from_forgery` check based on a parameter that I pass from the request in rake task?

Comment: have a look at `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` and the parameters you can use to configure it